# Gatsby with wordpress does not find an ACF flexible content field if it is unused

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I have a flexible content field type in Wordpress (with ACF) and I am getting errors when trying to build gatsby.

I use the following plugins:

- ACF to REST api
- ACF to REST api recursive
- Advanced Custom Fields PRO

For gatsby I use gatsby-source-wordpress.

```
{
  allWordpressPage {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        acf {
          page_builder_page {
            ... on WordPressAcf_hero {
              title
              subtitle
            }
            ... on WordpressAcf_text {
              text
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A query like the one above does work, only if the block *page_builder* on the *page* type for some page is using the *hero* and the *text* block. If I set up this page for the first time, or create a new custom post type with the same page_builder field, I need to fill at least one field for every flexible content block type before the graphql-query will work.

Otherwise I get errors similar to this for each unused block (if hero-type has content but not text-type for instance):

```
GraphQL request: Fragment "TextBlockFragment" cannot be spread here as objects of
type "WordPressAcf_hero" can never be of type "WordPressAcf_text".
```

Is there a solution to this? I guess it is not supposed to be this way. As it is now, I need to fill the whole page with dummy content the first time it is set up before I can actually build it with Gatsby.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue you’re having is similar to [a fairly common one](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3344) I’ve also encountered when using Gatsby + the WordPress REST API.

A brief summary is that the WordPress REST API will, for example, return a boolean when there is an ACF gallery field with no images, rather than `null`, which is what the GraphQL query is expecting when the field is empty. I suspect the same thing is happening for you: you are querying for the subfields that haven’t been filled out, and you are getting a response that GraphQL interprets as the wrong type, instead of `null`. (Full disclosure, my only experience with GraphQL is via Gatsby.)

Luckily, I think there are a lot of options for you to resolve this.

### New Gatsby solution

The Gatsby team and contributors have been working on this one pretty actively recently, and you can currently try out a preview version of the new approach here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-04-new-schema-customization/

You can read a lot more about the issue and background here, if you want: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3344

### Existing, quick WordPress solutions

The two solutions that work around this now, if you don’t want to use something not completely merged into Gatsby yet:

1. [Setting empty responses to `null` for that ACF field as described by @pieh on the Gatsby team](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4461#issuecomment-371775563), and there are more examples in that GitHub issue for other field types
2. Creating “dummy” content, where everything is filled out, and then that post is filtered out before being displayed (ex. when the slug is `placeholder`). The catch here is you have these fake posts for each Custom Post Type that cannot be deleted from WordPress.

I’ve used both approaches, and both work. I would say #2 was probably more reliable as it works for all the fields you are using at once, but is potentially more confusing depending on who is using the CMS: “Why are these posts here?”

Hope that’s helpful!